# how do i update array of objects in Zustand?

Tags: react-hooks, zustand

i am trying to update the masterSteps variable inside the store but the store is undefined that's why it is saying MasterSteps is undefined but on similar way the setRoute method is working and routekey variable is getting set

```
const useStore = create((set) => ({
    ...initialState,
    routeKey: "",
    MasterSteps: [],
    setRoute: (routeKeyToUse) => {
        set((state) => {
            state.routeKey = routeKeyToUse;
            
        })
    },
    setMasterSteps: (o) => {
        set((state) => { 
            state.MasterSteps= [...state.MasterSteps, o ]
    })},
   
}));
```

NOTE : the o as parameter in setMasterSteps is having data

i am expecting how to setState the array in zustand store

Answer (score 0):

Setter function should return new state, not imperativerly update it.

Try:

```
o => {
    set((state) => ({ MasterSteps:  [...state.MasterSteps, o ] }))
}
```

**Edit:**
Can you try:

```
const useStore = create((set) => ({
...initialState,
routeKey: "",
MasterSteps: [],
setRoute: (routeKeyToUse) => {
    set((state) => ({
        routeKey: routeKeyToUse;
    }))
},
setMasterSteps: (o) => {
    set((state) => ({ 
        MasterSteps: [...state.MasterSteps, o ]
    }))},
}));
```

Also what is definition of initialData? If it provides value for MasterSteps, it's overwritten by later MasterSteps = [].

Comment: MasterSteps is undefined it says. and not setting the data

Comment: @NEWTALENT are you trying to replace MasterSteps with o or add o element to end of MasterSteps?

Comment: I fetched The data from server and tring to setState in MasterSteps array. but the state.MasterSteps is giving me undefined

Comment: See editted answer please.

Comment: Also be careful, that useStore is a hook and as such can only be used in react components or other hooks.

Comment: what is the difference between the edited answer and the answer you gave first @Matija Sirk